# PHP Class not found when already loaded

Tags: php

Somehow this part of my class does not seem to work. In other methods I'm using the same Package class and it does not give an error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
$package = Package::get('Package', $data['Package']);
```

This is the error log:

```
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:06.304734 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2231] [client 10.0.2.2:55056] framework/Framework.php loaded!
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:06.304809 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2231] [client 10.0.2.2:55056] framework/Auth.php loaded!
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:06.304978 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2231] [client 10.0.2.2:55056] framework/Router.php loaded!
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:06.305747 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2231] [client 10.0.2.2:55056] src/controllers/DefaultController.php loaded!
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:06.305876 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2231] [client 10.0.2.2:55056] framework/View.php loaded!
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:06.305922 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2231] [client 10.0.2.2:55056] framework/Model.php loaded!
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:06.305933 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2231] [client 10.0.2.2:55056] src/models/Package.php loaded!
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:06.306602 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2231] [client 10.0.2.2:55056] framework/Result.php loaded!
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:11.336808 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2381] [client 10.0.2.2:55058] framework/Framework.php loaded!, referer: http://localhost/admin
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:11.337218 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2381] [client 10.0.2.2:55058] framework/Auth.php loaded!, referer: http://localhost/admin
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:11.337306 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2381] [client 10.0.2.2:55058] framework/Router.php loaded!, referer: http://localhost/admin
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:11.338517 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2381] [client 10.0.2.2:55058] src/controllers/PackageController.php loaded!, referer: http://localhost/admin
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:11.338572 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2381] [client 10.0.2.2:55058] src/Utils.php loaded!, referer: http://localhost/admin
[Tue Sep 10 12:20:11.347229 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2381] [client 10.0.2.2:55058] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Package' not found in /var/www/html/src/controllers/PackageController.php:115\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/framework/Framework.php(21): PackageController::upload()\n#1 /var/www/html/index.php(41): Framework::do()\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/src/controllers/PackageController.php on line 115, referer: http://localhost/admin
```

**UPDATE:**

For some reason it doesn't load the Package class properly when the upload button is clicked.

```
[Tue Sep 10 12:51:04.802059 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2230] [client 10.0.2.2:55774] framework/Framework.php loaded!, referer: http://localhost/admin
[Tue Sep 10 12:51:04.802103 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2230] [client 10.0.2.2:55774] framework/Auth.php loaded!, referer: http://localhost/admin
[Tue Sep 10 12:51:04.802155 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2230] [client 10.0.2.2:55774] framework/Router.php loaded!, referer: http://localhost/admin
[Tue Sep 10 12:51:04.802581 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2230] [client 10.0.2.2:55774] src/controllers/PackageController.php loaded!, referer: http://localhost/admin
[Tue Sep 10 12:51:04.802610 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2230] [client 10.0.2.2:55774] src/Utils.php loaded!, referer: http://localhost/admin
[Tue Sep 10 12:51:04.810391 2019] [php7:error] [pid 2230] [client 10.0.2.2:55774] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Package' not found in /var/www/html/src/controllers/PackageController.php:115\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/framework/Framework.php(21): PackageController::upload()\n#1 /var/www/html/index.php(41): Framework::do()\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/src/controllers/PackageController.php on line 115, referer: http://localhost/admin
```

This is the code that should load the classes:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
  $try = [
    'src/models/%s.php',
    'src/controllers/%s.php',
    'src/%s.php',
    'framework/%s.php',
  ];

  foreach ($try as $path) {
    $s = sprintf($path, $class);
    if (file_exists($s)) {
      require $s;
      error_log($s . " loaded!");
      return;
    }
  }

  return false;
});
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
I debugged some of the importers:

```
[Tue Sep 10 13:15:57.424301 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 2381] [client 10.0.2.2:56076] src/models/Package.php does not exists, referer: http://localhost///admin
```

It is not found, while it is the right location. It is possible that it has to do with the triple slashes?

Comment: Have you tried checking the namespaces (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)? It seems that you're using some framework and it might have a namespace on some of the files. Try adding a "\" backslash in front of the class name ```\Package::get('Package', $data['Package']);``` and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @PlanetCloud unfortunately it is not working. I'll see if I can find something else.

Comment: Hmmm, If that is the case, I suggest you check the class definition and see if there's a namespace near the top. Example of namespace ```namespace App\Http\Controllers;``` This is located near the top of the file.

Comment: Also isn't there.

Comment: If you believe that the class ```Package``` is **loaded** and **accessible** from ```/var/www/html/src/controllers/PackageController.php```, then you must have missed something. Adding a backslash should solve the problem if the ```Package``` class is defined on root namespace because the backslash functions like a pointer to the root. The ```Package``` class must have another namespace assigned to it. Check where the class is **defined** not where it is **used/called** and  see if there is namespace set

Comment: With your latest update, it seems that the upload did not follow the regular request path. Maybe there's a difference in namespace there or class names get misspelled.. This is probably namespace problem, check https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php to learn more on how to import the namespace.

Comment: I've posted a new update.